# Mounting NTFS drive or folder as a Samba share on Raspbian Jessie

Tags: mount, samba, raspbian, ntfs, ntfs-3g

I'm working on a Raspberry Pi B+ with Raspbian Jessie.  As far as I can tell, the drive is mounted read/write, but there's some kind of problem with where my Samba share is pointing to the mount point or folder on it, because when I try to access the share from a Windows 7 Pro 64 bit machine, I can't see the contents of the share.  I can see the shares, and I can try to authenticate, but I'm not sure if authentication is working.

I remember having problems doing this on Raspbian Wheezy, and I think ultimately I had to use UUIDs in the fstab file and set some permissions there or something.  Since I needed to do a whole bunch of work to this pi for other reasons, I upgraded to Jessie.  I can't find postings or questions where I asked about this before, so it must have been via chat or in person.

I'm more of a Windows user and have very little experience with Linux.  Most of it is aggravating people here on Stack Exchange where I am trying to follow instructions I found elsewhere.

The Samba log file for the machine I'm trying to connect from says:

```
  STATUS=daemon 'smbd' finished starting up and ready to serve connectionsprocess_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/rootshar failed. Permission denied
[2016/02/08 18:56:49.771190,  0] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4366(process_usershare_file)
  process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/rootshar failed. No such file or directory
[2016/02/08 18:56:49.775938,  0] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4366(process_usershare_file)
  process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/rootshar failed. No such file or directory
[2016/02/08 18:56:50.769876,  0] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4366(process_usershare_file)
  process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/rootshar failed. Permission denied
[2016/02/08 18:56:50.774827,  0] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4366(process_usershare_file)
  process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/rootshar failed. No such file or directory
[2016/02/08 18:56:50.782438,  0] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4366(process_usershare_file)
  process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/rootshar failed. No such file or directory
```

You'll note the timestamps are hours old.  I have no newer entries in that log file.

**fstab file:**

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
/dev/sda1       /media/5TBDrive auto    noatime           0       0

# a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
#   use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
```

**$ sudo mount**

```
/dev/mmcblk0p2 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,data=ordered)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=218244k,nr_inodes=54561,mode=755)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=22,pgrp=1,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /boot type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sda1 on /media/5TBDrive type fuseblk (rw,noatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=44504k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

**$ lsusb**

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:0963 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bc2:3312 Seagate RSS LLC
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**smb.conf**

```
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   dns proxy = no
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   syslog = 0
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   server role = standalone server
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
   usershare allow guests = yes
[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700
   directory mask = 0700
   valid users = %S
[RootShare]
   comment = Root Share
   path = /media/5TBDrive
   #valid users = @users
   #force group = users
   #create mask = 0660
   #directory mask = 0771
   read only = no
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not know there was a way to test the samba configuration.  There is, and it's included with Raspbian Jessie.  It's called testparm, and part of samba-tool.

```
samba-tool testparm
```

Running this told me that I had an invalid configuration, and that the hostname I was using was invalid.  In my case it was 1 character too long.  Overriding the name with `netbios name =` completely fixed the system.  I suspect that the samba server could not work properly with the wrong name.

Prior to fixing the name, I has escalated logging levels by adding `log level = 3` and from what I could tell, it looked like all users were being ignored or interpreted as a guest user.